# Dotnet on AWS Lambda : How many request will go to one container at once?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-lambda

Using the serverless template for dotnet core 2.1,

How many request will be served at once by one AWS lambda container?

I am getting into a memory issue with one big request that takes up to more than 2Gbs of RAM. If in that time frame while that request is being processed, the same container serve another request, It will surely fails. Can anyone confirm this will happen or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda containers/invocations are completely isolated. So large memory usage / slow running / segfaults / etc. will only ever effect that current request.

The only caveat to this is if you have a memory leak. AWS might reuse an already initialised container for that function to serve a later request. If your function is leaking memory then whatever has been leaked will remain leaked until the container killed by AWS. Although if an invocation fails because of out-of-memory AWS will likely kill it.

Containers are typically very short lived. AWS does not give any guarantees (indeed, it recommends you assume *no* container reuse), but anecdotally even heavily used containers do not last longer than an hour.